# Flex Container Width Doesn't Adhere to Min-Content of Elements with max-width: 100% and flex-shrink: 0

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I have found a situation where the width of a container doesn't follow the min-content of its elements when both max-width: 100% and flex-shrink: 0 are used on a flex child element.
Flexbox seem to know that I don't want my SVG to shrink, but it ignores the final size for the flexible container when flex container equal to its min-content.

```css
.container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: min-content;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.box {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="_FaHeart_15enc_28" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M47.6 300.4L228.3 469.1c7.5 7 17.4 10.9 27.7 10.9s20.2-3.9 27.7-10.9L464.4 300.4c30.4-28.3 47.6-68 47.6-109.5v-5.8c0-69.9-50.5-129.5-119.4-141C347 36.5 300.6 51.4 268 84L256 96 244 84c-32.6-32.6-79-47.5-124.6-39.9C50.5 55.6 0 115.2 0 185.1v5.8c0 41.5 17.2 81.2 47.6 109.5z"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

This seems to have a relation with the min-width of my SVG since an SVG doesn't have one.
I generally always set my image and svg to max-width 100% for better responsive design.
I found this issue when trying to resize my browser as low as possible to reproduce the min-content of my flex parent.
I would like to have more explantation how it really work and what would be the best practice.

Comment: So what do you think *should* happen?